# adding files in /etc/sudoers.d/

Tags: permissions, sudo

I just joined an ubuntu 18.04 server to my windows domain. I want to add domain admins as sudoers on the ubuntu server. I created a file /etc/sudoers.d/domain_admins. I added %DOMAIN.COM\Domain\ Admins        ALL=(ALL) ALL. When I tested a sudo command, with my domain admin, I got the message that it wasn't in the sudoers file. I checked the permissions on the file and noticed it was given 47. I did a chmod of 0440 but that did not seem to work as it's still set as 47. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I *think* that the appropriate syntax is `%Domain\ Admins@DOMAIN.COM` but don't quote me... (I'm assuming the AD group name is `Domain Admins`)

Comment: I found this, though... Because a number of AD groups have spaces in the names, you’ll need to escape the spaces using backslashes. For example. adding the following entry to /etc/sudoers would allow you to give full sudo permissions to an AD group named Group Name With Spaces:

1
%DOMAIN\\Group\ Name\ With\ Spaces       ALL=(ALL) ALL
In both cases, replace DOMAIN with your AD domain’s name.

Comment: Sure - that may work as well, but note that you will need to escape both spaces **and** backslashes i.e. `%DOMAIN.COM\\Domain\ Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Comment: For some reason in the post, is not showing two backslashes, but they are there. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out Just put this '`Domain\ Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL`' without the ' '